# How fast can molecular vibrations become under the application of IR radiation?

Tags: energy, frequency, vibrations, molecules, infrared-radiation

It is my understanding that IR radiation can be absorbed by molecules when the frequency of the photon matches the natural frequency of the bonds in the molecule which can cause the amplitude and speed of the molecular vibrations to increase. My question is how fast can atoms in the molecule be made to vibrate through the continuous application of IR light at specific frequencies? How much energy would this take?

Comment: eagerly awaiting an answer! +1 -NN